# R - fill rows of a column down based on another row in another column

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I am reading in JSON data in RStudio that is coming from sensors driving around
   in a city.
I am then converting this data to a dataframe with the sofa
   and jsonlite package. the data basically is sensor data, that
   consists of location data, and to each location measurement there are
   some environmental data transmitted and coded in resource paths like
   (/6/0/0 and /6/0/1 for latitude and longitude information) - due to
   the JSON data I am reading in, the location information in my R
   dataframe is in the same "value" column like the environmental data
   like humidity, CO2 etc. so I loose the location information for the
   individual observations, as the location info is also treated as
   value. see converted JSON data.frame below

> data.frame

```
> |------------------------------------------------------- |    
> resourcePath    |     value  |UTC       |lat     |long . |
>   
> /6/0/0          |    48.18   |14:51:43 |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/1          |    16.39   |14:51:43 |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/515/5700  |         34 |14:52:43 |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/289/5700  |         15 |14:53:43 |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/515/5700  |        55  |4:53:47  |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/289/5700  |       9004 |14:54:23 |  0     | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3304/0/5700    |       367  | 14:54:34| 0      |0       |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3315/0/5700    |         47 |14:54:54 | 0      |0       |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/0          |     50.34  |14:57:11 |0       | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/1          |     20.52  |14:57:13 |0       | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3304/0/5700    |         84 |14:57:34 |0       | 0      |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3315/0/5700    |         56 |14:57:45    0       0      |
```

And here a View of the desired dataframe.

[this is the desired df - each row has an associated "lat" and "long" information - depending on the value in the "value" column, as long as there is a new value in the "value" column.][2]

```
> |------------------------------------------------------- |    
> resourcePath    |     value  |UTC       |lat     |long . |
>   
> /6/0/0          |    48.18   |14:51:43 |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/1          |    16.39   |14:51:43 |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/515/5700  |         34 |14:52:43 |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/289/5700  |         15 |14:53:43 |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/515/5700  |        55  |4:53:47  |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3300/289/5700  |       9004 |14:54:23 |  48.18 | 16.39  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3304/0/5700    |       367  | 14:54:34| 48.18  |16.39   |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3315/0/5700    |         47 |14:54:54 | 48.18  |16.39   |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/0          |     50.34  |14:57:11 |50.34   | 20.52  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /6/0/1          |     20.52  |14:57:13 |50.34   | 20.52  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3304/0/5700    |         84 |14:57:34 |50.34   | 20.52  |
> |---------------|------------|---------|--------|--------|   
> /3315/0/5700    |         56 |14:57:45    50.34   20.52  |
```

I was looping - using lapply, but currently i am not getting the desired df.
Any hints widely appreciated.
Thomas

Comment: Without see the JSON data, it is difficult to impossible to provide any meaningful advice or suggestions.

Comment: @Dave2e: thought that the JSON data is not too relevant here as I already have my JSON data in an R dataframe. here is an excerpt of the JSON I am getting. "resources": [

        { "resourcePath":"/6/0/0" },         // GPS latitude in deg. North

        { "resourcePath":"/6/0/1" },         // GPS longitude in deg. East

        { "resourcePath":"/3300/256/5700" }, // CO conc. in ppb

        { "resourcePath":"/3300/257/5700" }, // SO2 conc. in ppb

        { "resourcePath":"/3300/258/5700" }, // NO conc. in ppb

        { "resourcePath":"/3300/515/5700" }, // NO2 conc. in ppb

Comment: The best way to solve this is during the process of converting the JSON data into a data frame.  Read the JSON as a list, write a function that builds a row for each observation, `lapply` it over the list, then combine the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with the use of the tidyr package.  This assumes the first row of each grouping of data is the "/6/0/0" row and the second row is "/6/0/1".

```
df<-structure(list(resourcePath = structure(c(5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("/3300/289/5700", "/3300/515/5700", 
"/3304/0/5700", "/3315/0/5700", "/6/0/0", "/6/0/1"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(48.18, 16.39, 34, 15, 55, 9004, 367, 47, 50.34, 
    20.52, 84, 56), UTC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("14:51:43", "14:52:43", 
    "14:53:43", "14:53:47", "14:54:23", "14:54:34", "14:54:54", 
    "14:57:11", "14:57:13", "14:57:34", "14:57:45"), class = "factor"), 
    lat = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    long = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("resourcePath", 
"value", "UTC", "lat", "long"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))    

f$resourcePath<-as.character(df$resourcePath)

#reset lat and long columns to NA for the fill command
df$lat<-NA
df$long <- NA

#find rows with the lat resource
#assumes this is the first row of each data grouping
latrows<-which(df$resourcePath=="/6/0/0")
df$lat[latrows]<-df$value[latrows]
df$long[latrows]<-df$value[(latrows+1)]

library(tidyr)  #needed for the fill function
df<-fill(df, lat, long)
```

Edit note: This is a performance improvement over the initial version, provide the row ordering is consistent in the dataframe.

Comment: that worked like a charm - even with a dataframe containing more than 200k rows. THANK You very much !!